Laravel feature test for download controller using mocking
I'm currently working on a feature test for a download controller that fetches files from storage. I've implemented mocking to simulate the download process using my FileService. However, as this is my first time using mocking in my tests, I'm unsure where I might have made a mistake in my code. Additionally, I'm encountering an error that I'm struggling to resolve. Any insights into what might be causing these issues would be greatly appreciated.
Encountered Error

API EXCEPTION {"message":"No matching handler found for Mockery_2_App_Services_FileUploadService::downloadDocument(). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

Download Feature Test

class FetchTest extends AuthTestCase
{
    private FileUploadService $fileUploadService;

    /**
     * This method is called before each test.
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->fileUploadService = app(FileUploadService::class);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called before next test for cleanup
     */
    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        Mockery::close();
    }

    /**
     * Test successfully fetching document by id
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_fetch_document_by_id_success()
    {
        $this->authenticate();

        Storage::fake(Product::DOCUMENT_PATH);
        [$product, $document] = $this->createDocument();
        $path = Product::DOCUMENT_PATH;
        $fullPath = $path . '/' . $document->name;
        Storage::disk(Product::DOCUMENT_PATH)->put($fullPath, 'test');
        
        $headers = [
            'Content-Disposition' => "documents; filename=$document->name",
            'Content-Length' => $document->size,
            'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
            'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
            'Expires' => '0',
        ];
 
        $outputs = $this->mockDownloadDocument($document->name, $headers, $path);
        [$filePath, $preview] = $outputs;

        $this->assertEquals($fullPath, $filePath);
        $preview->assertDownload();

        $response = $this->fetchDocument($product->id, $document->id);
        Log::info(print_r($response, true));

        $response->assertOk();

        Storage::disk(Product::DOCUMENT_PATH)->assertExists($fullPath);
        Storage::disk(Product::DOCUMENT_PATH)->assertMissing($fullPath);
    }

    /**
     * Mocking outputs for File Upload Service
     * 
     * @param string $fileName
     * @param array $headers
     * @param string|null $path
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    private function mockDownloadDocument(string $fileName, array $headers = [], ?string $path = null)
    {
        $exist = Storage::disk(Product::DOCUMENT_PATH)->exists($fileName);
        Log::info("File Exist: $exist");

        $fetchFileMock = Mockery::mock(FileUploadService::class);
        $filePath = $path ? "$path/$fileName" : $fileName;

        Log::info("File Path: $filePath");

        $fetchFileMock->shouldReceive('getFullPath')->with($fileName, $path)->andReturn($filePath);
        $fetchFileMock->shouldReceive('downloadDocument')->with($fileName, $headers, $path)->andReturn(Storage::download($filePath, $fileName, $headers));

        $this->app->instance(FileUploadService::class, $fetchFileMock);

        $fileUploadService = $this->app->make(FileUploadService::class);

        $filePath = $fileUploadService->getFullPath($fileName, $path);
        $preview = $fileUploadService->downloadDocument($fileName, $headers, $path);

        return [$filePath, $preview];
    }

    /**
     * Create Document
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    private function createDocument()
    {
        $supplierId = Supplier::factory()->create()->id;
        $product = Product::factory()->create(['supplier_id' => $supplierId]);
        $document = Document::factory()->create();
        ProductDocument::create(['product_id' => $product->id, 'document_id' => $document->id]);

        return [$product, $document];
    }

    /**
     * Fetch Document
     * 
     * @param int $productId
     * @param int $documentId
     * @return \Illuminate\Testing\TestResponse
     */
    private function fetchDocument(int $productId, int $documentId)
    {
        return $this->json('GET', "/api/products/$productId/documents/$documentId");
    }
}

Controller

public function __invoke(int $id, int $documentId)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $document = $product->documents()->findOrFail($documentId);

        if (!$document) {
            return $this->sendError('Document not found.');
        }

        try {
            $fileName = $document->name;
            $headers = [
                'Content-Disposition' => "documents; filename=$fileName",
                'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control' => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
                'Expires' => '0',
            ];

            return $this->fileUploadService->downloadDocument($fileName, $headers, Product::DOCUMENT_PATH . '/' . $id);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return $this->sendException($exception);
        }

FileService

class FileUploadService
{

 public function downloadDocument(string $fileName = '', array $headers = [], ?string $path = null)
    {
        $filePath = $this->getFullPath($fileName, $path);
        return Storage::download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
    }

 public function getFullPath(string $filename, ?string $prepend = null)
    {
        $filePath = $filename;
        if ($prepend) {
            return "$prepend/$filePath";
        }

        return $filePath;
    }
}

As you can see in my code I have tried to use mockery but the downloadDocument returns an error.
